# How can I POST data to a url using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: web-services, qt, post, symbian

I have a webservice that I need to POST some data to using Qt.
I figured that I can use a QByteArray when POSTing to the web service.

My question is, how can I format this array in order to be parsed correctly at the other end?

This is the code I have so far:

```
    // Setup the webservice url
    QUrl serviceUrl = QUrl("http://myserver/myservice.asmx");
    QByteArray postData;

   /* 
   Setup the post data somehow
   I want to transmit:
   param1=string,
   param2=string
   */

    // Call the webservice
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    networkManager->post(QNetworkRequest(serviceUrl), postData);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I used:

```
QByteArray postData;
postData.append("param1=string&");
postData.append("param2=string");
```

So & instead of newline after each parameter.

Comment: This approach does not protect against & characters being in the the input. If 'string' is user input, they could inject parameters.

Answer (score 137):

Since some parameters and values might need to be utf-8 and percent encoded (spaces, &, =, special chars...), you should rather use `QUrl` (for Qt 4) or `QUrlQuery` (for Qt 5) to build the posted string.

Example code for **Qt 4**:

```
QUrl postData;
postData.addQueryItem("param1", "string");
postData.addQueryItem("param2", "string");
...
QNetworkRequest request(serviceUrl);    
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, 
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
networkManager->post(request, postData.encodedQuery());
```

and for **Qt 5**:

```
QUrlQuery postData;
postData.addQueryItem("param1", "string");
postData.addQueryItem("param2", "string");
...
QNetworkRequest request(serviceUrl);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, 
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
networkManager->post(request, postData.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8());
```

Starting with Qt 4.8 you can also use [QHttpMultiPart](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhttpmultipart.html) if you need to upload files.

Comment: This is most definitely the most appropriate way of accomplishing the task in question. +1.

Comment: As of Qt 5, QUrl no longer has addQueryItem().

Comment: @mjk99 `QUrlQuery` does, but it doesn't have `.encodedQuery()`

Comment: Note that in Qt 4.8, `addQueryItem()` ["_does not encode spaces (ASCII 0x20) as plus (+) signs, like HTML forms do_"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qurl.html#addQueryItem)

Comment: I prefer to use `postData.query().toUtf8()`.

Answer (score 9):

Updating alexisdm answer to Qt5:

```
// Setup the webservice url
QUrl serviceUrl = QUrl("http://your.url");
QByteArray postData;

QUrlQuery query;
query.addQueryItem("param1","string1");
query.addQueryItem("param2","string2");

postData = query.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8();

// Call the webservice
QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        SLOT(onPostAnswer(QNetworkReply*)));

QNetworkRequest networkRequest(serviceUrl);
networkRequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

networkManager->post(networkRequest,postData);
```

Don't forget to include

```
QT += network
```

in .pro.

Comment: What this code does differently that just constructing a QByteArray like Juha, is that the postData is `"?param1=string1&param2=string2"`, which goes wrong.

Comment: If you are doing multiple requests using the same network access manager, it makes sense to connect the slot to the `finished()` signal of the `QNetworkReply` instead of `QNetworkAccessManager`. That way, you can have different signals per request and handle them separately, or handle data part by part using `readyRead()` signal.

Answer (score 6):

the actually answer is

```
QByteArray postData;
postData.append("param1=string&");
postData.append("param2=string");
```

**NOTE: use "&" here!!!**.

I didn't notice Juha's answer here, and waste much time on testing my code using the ",\n" approach.

Please change the correct answer to Juha's.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to handle this, i am using your code also to give a complete code:

```
     // Setup the webservice url         
     QUrl serviceUrl = QUrl("http://myserver/myservice.asmx");
     QByteArray postData;

     QUrl params;
     params.addQueryItem("param1","string1");
     params.addQueryItem("param2","string2");

     postData = params.encodedQuery();

     // Call the webservice
     QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
     connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

      networkManager->post(QNetworkRequest(serviceUrl), postData);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
QByteArray postData;
postData.append("param1=string,\n");
postData.append("param2=string\n");
```