# Qt Simple Post Request

Tags: qt, post

I'm looking to do a very simple POST request to a webpage. The page is in php and will take whatever is posted check it against a database then respond with a key if the item is in the database.

I have not a clue how to use post requests inside Qt or how to get information returned and store it back into a variable within Qt. Any help would be highly appreciated as I am starting from a blank on the Qt side.

I've looked at the other examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348359/qt-https-post-request

[How can I POST data to a url using QNetworkAccessManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599423/how-can-i-post-data-to-a-url-using-qnetworkaccessmanager)

but I don't see how to store a response from the php script

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Connect the **QNetworkAccessManager** signal finished to your slot and using **QNetworkReply** you should read all the contents of the webpage.

Here is a get example it can be easily adapted for the post method.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager * mgr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(onfinish(QNetworkReply*)));
    connect(mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),mgr,SLOT(deleteLater()));

    mgr->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.google.com")));

}

void MainWindow::onfinish(QNetworkReply *rep)
{
    QByteArray bts = rep->readAll();
    QString str(bts);
    QMessageBox::information(this,"sal",str,"ok");

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question on how to do a POST request, post needs data, this is simply a GET request.

Comment: Why wouldn't you add the eaxmple of a post? This answer gets shown at duckduckgo, but this isn't a correct answer

Answer (score 12):

opc0de previous answer is not a POST to me but a GET.

Here is how to do a POST Request

```
void xxx::postRequest(QByteArray & postData)
{
    QUrl url = QUrl("abc.com");


    QNetworkAccessManager * mgr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    connect(mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(onFinish(QNetworkReply*)));
    connect(mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),mgr,SLOT(deleteLater()));

    QHttpMultiPart http;

    QHttpPart receiptPart;
    receiptPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"data\""));
    receiptPart.setBody(postData);

    http.append(receiptPart);

    mgr->post(QNetworkRequest(url), http);
}

void xxx::onFinish(QNetworkReply *rep)
{

}
```

from the doc [here.](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qhttpmultipart.html)

Comment: `mgr->post(QNetworkRequest(url), http);` doesn't compile in Qt 5.15 (no matching function)

Comment: @M.M  I don't think OP can write a code that can be valid for every damn Qt version.

Comment: @AbbasPerçin even though It is usual in StackOverflow to update answers with newer or easier or more elegant solutions, i don't believe M.M is asking for an update but letting others know that they are not alone experiencing this issue. I also could not compile the code.

Comment: This function seems to still exist in Qt5.15 -> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#post-2 perhaps you have Qt compiled with some missing flags or is it a bug within Qt? @M.M

Comment: @Damien maybe the documentation is out of date?

Comment: Try mgr->post(QNetworkRequest(url), &http);  @M.M

Answer (score 8):

```
QNetworkAccessManager * manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

QUrl url("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
QNetworkRequest request(url);

request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

QUrlQuery params;
params.addQueryItem("client_id", "...");
params.addQueryItem("client_secret", "...");
params.addQueryItem("code", "...");
// etc

connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));

manager->post(request, params.query().toUtf8());
```

[source](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/42545-HTTP-request-POST-in-QT-application?p=194678#post194678)

Comment: This adds those items to the URL, no? How do I add items to the body?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Sorry, I don't know, I did this a while ago.