# How POST QList of int to my webservice in qt?

Tags: qt, qml, qnetworkaccessmanager, qurl

I have an `QList` of `int` and I want with post request send it to web service

```
QList<int> list;
QUrlQuery query ;
QNetworkReply* reply= postRequest(query,"www.myapi.com/api/Book/SaveDigits");//a method that will send POST request
connect(reply,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(getListFinished()));
```

but I don't know how add this list of interger to `QUrlQuery`?

I had before post Class Data like below?

```
QUrlQuery postData;
postData.addQueryItem("UserName",userName());
postData.addQueryItem("Password",password());
```

I use aps.net webapi2 for my webservice

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SaveDigits(UserInfo userInfo)
 {
 }
```

above code works for post data as `UserInfo' class but when i want to save List it don't work

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SaveDigits(List<int> list)
 {
 }
```

**But how can i send `QList<int>` ?**

Comment: `QList list` ?? shouldn't it be `QList<int> list`

Comment: @MohammadKanan Yes.I have edit question

Comment: what's  `postRequest`

Comment: my question is how add list of integers to qurlquery? post request is method that will post data

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599423/how-can-i-post-data-to-a-url-using-qnetworkaccessmanager)

Comment: but `QUrlQuery` takes  `_key_/_value_` item pairs .. lists are not `_key_/_value_` pairs ?

Comment: @MohammadKanan yes,I want this,how do this?how post list of int?

Comment: Since you want to post integers only, use `QNetworkReply *QNetworkAccessManager::post(const QNetworkRequest &request, const QByteArray &data)` directly. i. e. manager->post(url, data). Convert your QList<int> to QByteArray or use QByteArray instead of QList<int> from begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `addQueryItem()` with the same key multiple times, the values won't overwrite each others.

Assuming you want the key to be called "digit", you can use something like this:

```
for(int value : list) {
    query.addQueryItem("digit", QString::number(value));
}
```

On the server side, most web service frameworks are smart enough to turn the key with multiple values into an array or a list.

Comment: It don't work.I use asp.net webapi2 for my webservic.

Comment: Ok.now it works.I have changed the parameter of action method as Class now it works